# Add another data coloumn from arduino sketch into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arduino

I found someone do it on wireless from [github](https://github.com/ericbenwa/POST-Arduino-Data-Wireless/blob/master/arduino_post/arduino_post.ino). I want to insert another column using arduino via ethernet shield to php apache server into mysql database. In the arduino sketch, I add another coloumndata as shown below:

```
 String yourdatacolumn1="yourdata1=";
    String yourdata1;
    int yourarduinodata1 = 55555555;
    yourdata1 = yourdatacolumn1 + yourarduinodata1;
```

In the mysql table, I have a column call yourdata1. and in the insert_sql.php. I have modified the code a little bit. But when I run the sketch. On php side, no data is recorded. If I get rid of the new column yourdata1. that works. But when inserting another column , it doesn't work. (I have also created column into mysql called yourdata1)

```
foreach ($_REQUEST as $key => $value)
{
    if ($key == "yourdata") {
        $yourdata = $value;

    }
    if ($key =="yourdata1"){
      $yourdata1=$value;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three steps to achieve what you want:

1. Create a column named `yourdata1` in your mysql table: (You have already done as per your question but I am reiterating)I am guessing you followed the steps mentioned in the README of this particular github project to create the columns: `yourdata` and `timestamp`. For your problem, you need to create another column, `yourdata1` similarly. Or alternatively you can login to the mysql client and issue the following command:

   ```
   ALTER TABLE your-table-name ADD COLUMN yourdata1 varchar(100)
   ```
2. Edit your insert_mysql.php to start adding data to your new column: Apart from the edit you have shown in the question, you also need to edit the line 23 of the script which inserts data into the table. The syntax for doing so can be found [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).I am mentioning it here so that you could use it

   ```
   INSERT INTO your-table-name (yourdata,yourdata1,timestamp) VALUES ($yourdata,$yourdata1,now());
   ```

   (Make sure that both $yourdata and $yourdata1 php variables exist, you can initialize both of them as empty, `$yourdata=''` and `$yourdata1=''` just before the for loop)
3. You need to make sure that arduino passes this new yourdata1 to your insert_php script. I guess you have already figured it out. You just need to add another `client.println()` statement.

Comment: I tried all of your steps but data capture. If I get rid of the yourdata1 information, then i can capture yourdata.

Comment: If I give a value like 111 to $yourdata1='111'; before foreach loop in the insert_sql.php  , then it can record. I think it is the problem from my arduino sketch, which they do not capture the yourdata1 value. I put another client.println  // client.println(yourdata.length());
   // client.println();
    client.println(yourdata); 
   // client.println(yourdata1.length());
   // client.println();
    client.println(yourdata1);   But still doesn't work